# how to do conditional date substraction in excel

Tags: excel

I am wondering how I can do a date subtraction in excel. I have case ID in column "A" and create date in column"B". I would like to see for duplicated cases, for how many days later was the same case ID assigned?
case ID Create date.

Here is an simple example. However, I got 100K rows of data in reality.

```
123 1/2/2011
124 1/3/2011
125 1/4/2011
123 1/5/2011
```

For case 123, I would like to get the result as 4 days.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Can you sort? I'm thinking to sort the two columns based on whatever `123` is (ID number?) - Then, you could just do an `If` statement like "If the ID in this row is same as above, subtract the two dates, else return nothing"?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(MAX(IF(A$2:A$5 = A2, B$2:B$5)) - MIN(IF(A$2:A$5 = A2, B$2:B$5)) = 0, 0, MAX(IF(A$2:A$5 = A2, B$2:B$5)) - MIN(IF(A$2:A$5 = A2, B$2:B$5)) + 1)
```

Where A has your case id's and B has your creation dates. Enter as an array formula with ctrl+shift+enter.

If you have triplicate or quadruplicate cases, this will return the difference between the first creation of the case and the last creation of the case. If you want to return the difference between the first and 2nd, 2nd and third, 3rd and fourth etc. etc. the strategy is a little different, but that example is not provided in the test data.

Note that you have to add 1 if you want to get 4, since this will return 3 due to how Excel's date subtraction rules work.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, put this formula into C4:

```
=B4-VLOOKUP(A4,$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `1/2/2011` is in B1 and the dates is ColumnB ascend and you want to count the the days between instances of the same ID  with today and tomorrow for example counting as `2`, please try in Row1 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$A2:B100000,2,0)-B1+1,"")
```